# MySQL turn rows into columns

Tags: mysql

I have a table that looks like this (d could be the day, and h1 h2 h3 the values of the single hours of the day(assuming the day has 3 hours)):

```
d  h1 h2 h3
1  1  2  3 
2  4  5  6
3  7  8  9
```

and I what an output like this (one row with all the hours):

```
d h value
1 1 1
1 2 2
1 3 3
2 1 4
2 2 5
2 3 6
3 1 7
3 2 8
3 3 9
```

Is there a way do this with MySQL?

Edit: Having to address every single column in the syntax should be avoided, because this is supposed to also work for a lot of columns.

Answer (score 0):

What you describe is more like "turn columns into rows". You can do this with `UNION [ALL]`.

The difference between `UNION` and `UNION ALL` is, that `UNION` does not return duplicates, it acts like `DISTINCT`. If you know, there won't be duplicates, you might as well use `UNION ALL` and spare your server the work to detect any.

```
SELECT
d, 1 as h, h1 as 'value'
FROM t
UNION ALL
SELECT
d, 2 as h, h2 as 'value'
FROM t
UNION ALL
SELECT
d, 3 as h, h3 as 'value'
FROM t
# optionally you can add
ORDER BY d, h, value
```

- see it working live in an [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/82898/1/0)

Comment: Very interesting solution! Is there also a way to do this, if there is one column per minute of the day instead of just 3 columns?

Comment: You mean you have 1440 columns? One column per minute of the day? If yes, then I'd suggest that you better find a solution to overcome the bad database design, instead of doing crazy queries. If it's an emergency, you can build a query by querying the information_schema database.

Comment: Thanks for the hint with the information_schema. How could I use this for the example given?